# C, design: removing global objects

Tags: c, global-variables

I'm creating a small Avida-style life simulation. I started out with a very basic, everything-is-global 600-line program in a single file to test some ideas, and now I want to create a real design.

Among other things, I had a global configuration object that every other function got something out of. Now, I must localize the object and pass pointers around. Thing is, mostly everyone needs this object. I've thought of three possible solutions:

- a) Keep the configuration object
  global (simplest, though not really a
  solution)
- b) Store pointers everywhere they are
  needed (easy enough, though a waste
  of memory, since some small
  plain-old-data structures would need
  it).
- c) Create factories for the POD types
  that need access to options, and have
  the factory perform all operations on
  them.

Of my ideas, only (c) sounds logical, but I don't want to needlessly complicate the structure. What would you guys do?

I'm fine with new ideas, and will provide whatever information about the program you want to know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's wrong with leaving it global?

Comment: @Carl Norum: Everything. Absolutely everything. There's plenty of material on how shockingly bad globals are easily accessible through Google.

Comment: @DeadMG, no kidding - imagine if I were to write a program with both global variables and a `goto` or two!  How could I ever live with myself for bringing the world to its fiery demise?

Comment: @Carl @DeadMG http://xkcd.com/292/ :P

Comment: Getting rid of global objects for the sake of getting rid of global objects is a case of premature optimization.

Comment: @MK @Carl yeah, after what Carl said I did some thinking. The problem of making this object local is that it's needed, well, globally. I can't think of a situation in which I would need more than one (that I can't solve with multiple processes). I think I'll just leave it global. Post this, with the rationale, as an answer!

Comment: @MK: Premature optimization?  The code is already written.  How is restructuring a program to conform to established good practices a premature optimization?

Comment: @Santiago Lezica: If the object isn't meant to be instantiated more than once, by all means leave it global.  If multiple threads are sharing the object, you might run into a bit of trouble (that's why POSIX mandates the re-entrant variant of the ISO C `strtok` function -- `strtok_r` -- for thread safety).  Other than that, making such a heavily-referenced single-instance object non-global will only complicate your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to agree with @Carl Norum: there is nothing wrong with the global config setup you have now. You say that everybody "got something out of" it. As you know, the problem with globals comes when everybody writes *into* them. In your case, the config info truly is needed globally so deserves to *be* global.

If you want to make it be a little more decoupled and protected -- a little less global-ish -- then why not add some read/write access routines.

See, storing pointers everywhere isn't going to really solve the problem: it will only add a layer of indirection that will merely disguise or camouflage what are, in reality, the global accesses that are making you nervous. And that extra layer of indirection will add *juuuuust* enough room for *juuuuust* a teeny-weeny little bug to creep in.

So, bottom line: if stuff is naturally global then *make* it global and don't worry about the usual widespread received wisdom that's mostly correct but might not be the right thing in your application. To always be bound by the rules/propaganda that CS teachers put out there is, imo, the perfect example of a foolish consistency.

Answer (score 2):

Global variables are awesome.  Spend your time actually getting something done instead of refactoring for no reason.  Every company I have worked at uses them **heavily**.

Ask yourself if you're actually gaining anything by moving it to an object you're just passing around everywhere.  Might as well save yourself the extra complexity..

Comment: @Santiago that's kind, thank you. Always glad to see someone else avoid wasting their time.

Answer (score 0):

Go for B, unless profiling proves it to be a problem. On most machines, the memory required to store a pointer is very, very trivial.